# how can i register vr controller input in godot 4?

Tags: godot4

I'm making a vr game in Godot 4.1, but I've hit a wall pretty early on. I can barely find any resources on how to get vr input at all, and none of that is for Godot 4. all I need is how to get input from the controllers.